# MongoDB reusing a collection for every user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm not sure the best way to set this up in MongoDB.

I have two collections `User` and `Skill`. The collection for `Skill` has a list of skills that every user should have.

```
var SkillSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});

mongoose.model('Skill', SkillSchema);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    first_name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    last_name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    email_address: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    skills: [{
        skill: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Skill' },
        count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        last_performed: { type: Date }
    }]
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

What I am trying to do is have a list of skills, and each user has a `count` property that shows how many times they have performed the skill, and a `last_performed` property that has the date they last performed it.

My problem is, I want the list of skills to be same for each user, but I can update their `count` and `last_performed` properties uniquely for each user.

The way I have got it currently is referencing the skill id, and then having the count/date in the user schema. The problem with this, is if I add another skill to the Skills schema, the user's skills array won't be updated with the new skill. I figured updating every user every time I add/remove a skill, to reflect the new skills list, wouldn't be the optimal way to do this.

Can you sync the user's skills array to match the Skills schema?

Would it be better to just add each user's count/date to the skill schema directly? The only problem with this is if there are thousands of users, would this have any performance problems, and would it be easy enough to sort the skills by count/date for each user, and query the user's skills individually without returning the counts for every user?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skills : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Skill' }]`. Just push the Ids to the array if you want to add skills when you do a save or an update.

you can populate the array of skills and you can count the skills array. That will give you the count.

If you have `last_performed` in the Skill model. then you will get access to it after you populate

Comment: The `count` property counts the amount of times the user has performed the skill not how many skills there are. Sorry for the confusion. The `count` and `last_performed` properties are unique to each user as well.

Comment: The maybe update the count in the skills and you could still do populate. I mean put the count in the Skill schema. Also maybe take a look at virtuals.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the easiest way to do it. I wasn't sure if storing thousands of `count` and `last_performed` values in each skill (once for each user) would be a hit to the performance when querying it or not.